# select distinct values on 1 column only in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 3 columns.

```
column_a, column_b, column_c
```

I am trying to get all the rows with making distinct only in column_a.

when i write

```
select distinct column_a,column_b,column_c
```

i think it gives me distinct pairs. So i have

```
value1 - a - b
value1 - a - c
```

I want to keep the distinct values of column_a following by column_b and column_c values cause i will create a table from that sql query and i want to add PK the column_a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the safest way is to use `row_number()`:

```
select a, b, c
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a order by a) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will return an arbitrary row for each `a` value, but `a` will not be repeated in the result set.